Redefining the part command and customizing the page layout
Here is my current code
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[
    headheight=55pt,
    paperheight=29.7cm,
    paperwidth=21cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    left=3cm,
    right=3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{libertine}
\def\uRomannumeral#1{\symbol{\numexpr"215F+#1\relax}}
\def\uRoman#1{\uRomannumeral{\the\value{#1}}}

\definecolor{pagecolor}{HTML}{313338}

\pagecolor{pagecolor}
\color{white}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\part{First Part}

\end{document}

There's a problem I don't know how to solve :

The libertine package changes the document font, which is undesirable.\I imported this package to be able to create a command that converts Arabic numbers into Roman numbers with the unicode character.


However, my goal here is to find someone who can help me customize the layout of the command \part
I would like to customize the command so that :

The command creates a custom layout on a single page (the default command leaves a blank page, which I do not want for now).
With the help of the graphicx package and the command \uRomannumeral (the one used to convert a number from Arabic numerals to Roman numerals), I want to reproduce, with dimensions as similar as possible, this template (which I made on Desmos due to my lack of LaTeX skills) → Desmos Representation of the page (Part Title is the value of what I entered between {} with \part)

And I would like the result to be as polished as possible. I’m aware that I’m asking for a lot, but I am detail-oriented, and I lack the skills and experience to attempt something like this. If you could provide me with some guidance or create a readable and complete code that won’t easily conflict with other potential packages, that would be truly amazing.

The libertine package provides access to (a clone of) the Linux Libertine font. The whole point of loading this package is to change the document font...

What should go in the empty red box on your desmos link?

Since you detail-oriented you need to provide a full spec not just an image where we expect to measure and pick the colors. You don't  know LaTeX well but also users here might not want to spent time to learn how to use desmos to determine these. What you need to provide numbering font, text font, sizes etc, definition of the gray and red colors can be in rgb etc.. The layout is easy to reproduce, but at least for me my crystal ball is broken.
